# Is there any dynamically produced .log file showing up the memory usage on FreeBSD?

Tags: logs, freebsd, top

I am using FreeBSD 10.1-RELEASE and I was just wondering if there is any .log file produced by default from the system because I am using ELK and I want to pass this file to logstash and then visualize the memory usage. Before going into any other solution where I have to install or do some hacking and produce a dynamic .log file I would really like to know if there is such a file produced by the system.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want some out-from-the-box log file, displaying how free/used RAM amount changes during the time. There is no such one in greenfield FreeBSD.